# Kendo UI ListBox removal depending on treeview check

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview, kendo-listbox

Hey all I am using KendoListBox and needing to loop through it and remove the selected [checked] items once I un-check the full category.

```js
let apiData = {
  "object_list": [{
    "Name": "facebook",
    "Description": null,
    "Id": "eb8cb0c8c32d1201bff30cf54S4f30889abb23f92b1f7",
    "DocumentType": null,
    "ProviderId": 2,
    "Cat": "Social Networks"
  }, {
    "Name": "twitter",
    "Description": null,
    "Id": "732fe66cce4365bc5074384f09b34e787f3f3efe8b55",
    "DocumentType": null,
    "ProviderId": 2,
    "Cat": "Social Networks"
  }, {
    "Name": "Google",
    "Description": null,
    "Id": "8b11d6f7b74bf71a7ddbc62dcfead27087e0f3e047e",
    "DocumentType": null,
    "ProviderId": 2,
    "Cat": "Search Engines"
  }]
};

$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
  checkboxes: {
    checkChildren: true
  },
  check: onCheck,
  dataSource: {
    data: apiData,
    schema: {
      model: {
        children: 'items'
      },
      parse: (data) => {
        // The new data array to be used by treeview
        let newData = [];

        data.object_list.forEach(item => {
          // Look for an already created parent for that categoty
          let parent = newData.find(parentItem => parentItem.text === item.Cat);

          // If not found...
          if (!parent) {
            // ... create a new one...
            parent = {
              id: 2,
              text: item.Cat,
              expanded: true,
              items: [],
              spriteCssClass: "folder"
            };

            // ... and add it to the final data array.
            newData.push(parent);
          }

          // Add the new item to the parent
          parent.items.push({
            id: 3,
            text: item.Name,
            spriteCssClass: "image"
          });
        });

        // Return the root object with its new child items
        return [{
          id: 1,
          text: 'Categories',
          expanded: true,
          spriteCssClass: "rootfolder",
          items: newData
        }];
      }
    }
  }
});

$("#Sources").kendoListBox();


function onCheck(e) {
  let checkedNodes = [],
checkedNode = e.node.innerText,
intx = 0,
listBox = $("#Sources").data("kendoListBox");

  //console.log(e.node.innerText);

  if (e.node.ariaChecked == "false") {
console.log("Its just now been selected *REMOVED*");
var node = listBox.dataSource.get("twitter");

//let listBoxItem = listBox.dataItems().find(item => item.text === e.node.innerText);
let listBoxItem = listBox.dataItems().find(item => "twitter" === "twitter");

console.log("listbox item: ", listBoxItem);


var text = e.node.innerText;
var textSpliced = text.split("\n").slice(1);

if (textSpliced.length >= 1) {
  $.each(textSpliced, function(tS) {
    console.log("splice: ", textSpliced[tS]);

    listBox.dataSource.remove(textSpliced[tS]);
  });
} else {
  /*
$("#Sources option").each(function(i){
    alert($(this).text() + " : " + $(this).val());*/
  //if (listBoxItem) {
  //console.log("list: ", listBoxItem);
  //listBox.dataSource.remove(listBoxItem);
//}
//}
//    });
}

  } else {
console.log("Its just now been selected *ADDED*");
listBox = $("#Sources").data("kendoListBox");


var text = e.node.innerText;
var textSpliced = text.split("\n").slice(1);

if (textSpliced.length >= 1) {
  $.each(textSpliced, function(tS) {
    console.log(textSpliced[tS]);

    listBox.add({
      text: textSpliced[tS],
      value: textSpliced[tS]
    });
  });
} else {
  listBox.add({
    text: checkedNode,
    value: checkedNode
  });
}
  }
}
```

```css
#treeview .k-sprite {
          background-image: url("../content/web/treeview/coloricons-sprite.png");
        }

        .rootfolder {
          background-position: 0 0;
        }

        .folder {
          background-position: 0 -16px;
        }

        .pdf {
          background-position: 0 -32px;
        }

        .html {
          background-position: 0 -48px;
        }

        .image {
          background-position: 0 -64px;
        }

        #filterText {
          width: 100%;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          padding: 6px;
          border-radius: 3px;
          border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/js/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2021.1.330/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<div id="treeview"></div>
<select id="Sources"></select>
```

I can do this

```
listBox.dataItems().find(item => item.text === e.node.innerText)
```

And be able to delete any 1 checked item. But if its more than 1 I am unable to figure out what I am missing.

So I tried doing this:

```
var text = e.node.innerText;
var textSpliced = text.split("\n").slice(1);

if (textSpliced.length >= 1) {
  $.each(textSpliced, function(tS) {
    console.log("splice: ", textSpliced[tS]);

    listBox.dataSource.remove(textSpliced[tS]);
  });
} else {}
```

But of course that did not produce any results - did not delete the items in the **kendoListBox**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this new approach:

```js
let apiData = {
  "object_list": [{
    "Name": "facebook",
    "Description": null,
    "Id": "eb8cb0c8c32d1201bff30cf54S4f30889abb23f92b1f7",
    "DocumentType": null,
    "ProviderId": 2,
    "Cat": "Social Networks"
  }, {
    "Name": "twitter",
    "Description": null,
    "Id": "732fe66cce4365bc5074384f09b34e787f3f3efe8b55",
    "DocumentType": null,
    "ProviderId": 2,
    "Cat": "Social Networks"
  }, {
    "Name": "Google",
    "Description": null,
    "Id": "8b11d6f7b74bf71a7ddbc62dcfead27087e0f3e047e",
    "DocumentType": null,
    "ProviderId": 2,
    "Cat": "Search Engines"
  }]
};

$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
  checkboxes: {
    checkChildren: true
  },
  check: onCheck,
  dataSource: {
    data: apiData,
    schema: {
      model: {
        children: 'items'
      },
      parse: (data) => {
        // The new data array to be used by treeview
        let newData = [];

        data.object_list.forEach(item => {
          // Look for an already created parent for that categoty
          let parent = newData.find(parentItem => parentItem.text === item.Cat);

          // If not found...
          if (!parent) {
            // ... create a new one...
            parent = {
              id: 2,
              text: item.Cat,
              expanded: true,
              items: [],
              spriteCssClass: "folder"
            };

            // ... and add it to the final data array.
            newData.push(parent);
          }

          // Add the new item to the parent
          parent.items.push({
            id: 3,
            text: item.Name,
            spriteCssClass: "image"
          });
        });

        // Return the root object with its new child items
        return [{
          id: 1,
          text: 'Categories',
          expanded: true,
          spriteCssClass: "rootfolder",
          items: newData
        }];
      }
    }
  }
});

$("#Sources").kendoListBox();

function onCheck(e) {
  let listBox = $("#Sources").data("kendoListBox"),
      treeView = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView"),
      selection = [],
      getSelection = (items) => {
        items.forEach(item => { 
          if (item.hasChildren) getSelection(item.items);
          else if (item.checked) selection.push(item);
        });
      };

  listBox.remove(listBox.items());
  getSelection(treeView.dataSource.data());
  
  if (selection.length) {
    selection.forEach(item => {
      listBox.add({
        text: item.text,
        value: item.value
      });
    });
  }
}
```

```css
#treeview .k-sprite {
          background-image: url("../content/web/treeview/coloricons-sprite.png");
        }

        .rootfolder {
          background-position: 0 0;
        }

        .folder {
          background-position: 0 -16px;
        }

        .pdf {
          background-position: 0 -32px;
        }

        .html {
          background-position: 0 -48px;
        }

        .image {
          background-position: 0 -64px;
        }

        #filterText {
          width: 100%;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          padding: 6px;
          border-radius: 3px;
          border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/js/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2021.1.330/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<div id="treeview"></div>
<select id="Sources"></select>
```

Comment: Wow. You figured it out and also did so with less code! Thanks again DontVoteMeDown!

Comment: I think there is a little bug in the code. If i start out with all the options un-expanded and click on a check next to the category name it does not add anything to the listbox. However, when I do expand it and click on the same check box category it does add them all to the listbox? http://jsfiddle.net/stealthrt/20p3osky/28/

Comment: @StealthRT probably because the nodes are not rendered before the first expand

Comment: I dont think kendo has anything to render them before hand?

Comment: I guess i can always do this: **$("#treeview").getKendoTreeView().expand(".k-sprite.folder"); $("#treeview").getKendoTreeView().collapse(".k-sprite.folder");**

Comment: @StealthRT thats the easiest way but not the best, as the user can spot the treeview opening and closing its nodes by itself. Other way is to work on the widget's data and not the nodes, as the data has the `checked` property even without nodes being rendered.

Comment: Wouldn't that be the same though? Using **expanded: true,** seems to be just like the **$("#treeview").getKendoTreeView().expand**? Are you saying there's a way of using the  **expanded: true,** and then changing it back to false as it adds each item to the list?

Comment: @StealthRT Sry i didnt get the point of your last comment